# Use CTE with dynamic SQL in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sql-cte

I have a stored procedure that uses a CTE, however the table to be consulted is variable (I have several tables with the same structure), so I try use dynamic SQL.

But it returns an error ("incorrect syntax near 'set'"), because I'm not referencing the CTE in query because dynamic SQL doesn't count (according [Incorrect syntax after CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561106/incorrect-syntax-after-cte))

So how do I resolve this? I have this query:

```
--Dynamic SQL
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
--Extract hour value
DECLARE @hourDate DATETIME = DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,@beginDate),0);
DECLARE @minutes INT = DATEPART(minute,@beginDate);
DECLARE @outmin INT;
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @interval INT=15;

--Verify Next Minute
IF @minutes <= 14 
    SET @outmin = 14;
ELSE IF @minutes > 14 AND @minutes <=29
    SET @outmin = 29;
ELSE IF @minutes > 29 AND @minutes <= 44
    SET @outmin = 44;
ELSE IF @minutes > 44 AND @minutes <=59
    SET @outmin = 59;

--Add Minute
SET @startDate = DATEADD(minute,@outmin,@hourDate);

;WITH Dates(Date) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @interval, @StartDate) AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @interval, Date) AS Date
    FROM Dates
    WHERE Date < @endDate
)

set @sql='SELECT a.Date
FROM  Dates a
left join '+ @tableName +' b on a.Date=b.TimeStampFrame
where b.TimeStampFrame is null
ORDER BY a.Date ASC
option (maxrecursion 0)'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With dynamic SQL its all or nothing, not half and half. So you have to put the entire query into dynamic SQL.

Comment: Just shove that CTE into your @sql string and rerun. Remember that a CTE is mostly just syntactic sugar for a subquery and since you wouldn't leave a subquery out of your dynamic sql string, you can't leave your CTE out of it for the same reason.

Comment: You can also put the insert the output of CTE into a #temporary table and then use that inside dynamic sql.

Comment: Aside... `;` is a statement terminator character, not a statement begininator (as some people are fond of saying). i.e.: don't use `;WITH`. _Although the semicolon isn't required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version._ ref: [Transact-SQL syntax conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql)

Comment: Two more comments in addition to the comments above:  1st: Make sure your `@tableName` variable is white-listed (this is a general advice for using dynamic SQL) and 2nd: Try to avoid using recursive CTEs for things that can be done using a calendar/tally table. For more information, read . Jeff Moden's [Hidden RBAR: Counting with Recursive CTE's](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes)